# How can I save string value on Substrate

Tags: substrate

1. I want to save "String" Value on Substrate
2. At First, I use "Vec" But It's not recognized by Polkadot JS
3. I use "Bytes",So I get the below error
4. How can I solve this problem?

Please help me.

- Is it correct to use "Bytes" as a way to store strings?
- If correct, how can I fix the error below?
- If not, what is correct to use?
- Please let me know if you have sample code

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod mock;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;

#[derive(Clone, Eq, PartialEq, Default, Encode, Decode, Hash)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug))]
pub struct TestData<BlockNumber,Bytes> {
    pub name: Bytes,                                                                                                                                                                    
    pub address: Bytes,
}
pub type TestDataOf<T> = TestData<primitives::Bytes>;
--snip--
// This pallet's storage items.
decl_storage! {
    // It is important to update your storage name so that your pallet's
    // storage items are isolated from other pallets.
    // ---------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        pub TestDatas: map hasher(blake2_128_concat) T::AccountId => Option<TestDataOf<T>>;
    }
}
--snip--
decl_module! {
    /// The module declaration.
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        // Initializing errors
        // this includes information about your errors in the node's metadata.
        // it is needed only if you are using errors in your pallet
        type Error = Error<T>;

        // Initializing events
        // this is needed only if you are using events in your pallet
        fn deposit_event() = default;


        /// regist public data
        #[weight = 10_000]
        pub fn register_test_data(origin, name:Bytes, address:Bytes) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
            let registerer = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            let test_data = TestDataOf::<T> {
                name,
                address,
            };
            <TestDatas<T>>::insert(&registerer, test_data);
            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
--snip--
```

Error is...

```
the trait `_::_parity_scale_codec::Encode` is not implemented for `TestData<substrate_primitives::Bytes>`
the trait `_::_parity_scale_codec::Decode` is not implemented for `TestData<substrate_primitives::Bytes>`
the trait `_::_parity_scale_codec::WrapperTypeEncode` is not implemented for `substrate_primitives::Bytes`
```

Comment: Hi @s.Takahashi, can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use a `Vec<u8>` to store arbitrary bytes in runtime storage like a string.

When accessing a `Vec<u8>` that is a string in Polkadot JS, you should use the type `Text`, which automatically handles parsing and converting this type to regular UTF-8 text.

Example:

Rust:

```
pub struct TestData {
    pub name: Vec<u8>,                                                                                                                                                                    
    pub address: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Polkadot JS Type Definition:

```
TestData: {
    name: 'Text',
    address: 'Text'
}
```

Let me know if this helps or if you have further issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to call my function by " Extrinsics " on Polkadot/Substrate Portal(https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/extrinsics). How can I define Polkadot JS Type Definition?

Comment: @Shin go to `Settings` > `Developer` and you will see a JSON input where you can define your JS types. Note there are helpful informational guides on how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again.
I can call my function how you told me.
Thank you so much!

This question is solved.

Comment: After `scale_info::TypeInfo` was introduced, It does not need to config JS type, if a field contain no-ASCII, it can't interpreted as string, just a hex string. How to fix it?

Comment: @gfan, yes, you are correct in the latest version we don't need to explicitly define any type, and in the case of strings, after using Vec<u8> in your pallet you can directly pass the string(text) format in polkadot.js portal, and you will be getting the same values back when you fetch from storage.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Further more  what my wondering is : when config `name: 'Text'` in polkadot.js portal, the vec<u8> data can be represented as a utf-8 readable string, but after use `scale_info::TypeInfo`, polkadot.js portal only represents it as hex string. How to let the polkadot display a human-readable string?

Comment: I am importing both FRAME support and system preludes but I am getting a type not found for `Vec<u8>` when adding it to a field in a storage map struct.