# error[E0412]: cannot find type `String` in this scope

Tags: rust, substrate, rust-ink

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]

mod XYZ {

    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Xyz {
        token_id: u32,
        serial_code: String
    }
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
             serial_code: String
   |                      ^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're explicitly excluding std ?

Comment: String is not part of the Substrate and Ink environments because it increases binary/compiled sizes (likely because of the UTF8 handling).
Use `Vec<u8>` to store this kind of data if you have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63459771/how-do-i-save-a-string-value-on-substrates-smart-contract-platform-ink/67065138#67065138) - you should use the `String` type included *in* `ink!`

```rust
use ink_prelude::string::String;
```

And include in the correct Cargo.toml file:

```
[Dependencies]
ink_prelude = { version = "2", git = "github.com/paritytech/ink", tag = "latest-v2", package = "ink_prelude", default-features = false }"
```

(or whatever version is correct for you)

Comment: After including the above, include "ink_prelude = { version = "2", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/ink", tag = "latest-v2", package = "ink_prelude", default-features = false }" in the [dependencies] of Cargo.toml file.