# String and Vec<u128> not found in this scope

Tags: substrate

I have following code in decl_storage!

```
Group get(fn group): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) u128 => Vec<u128>;
VoteStatus get(fn vote_status): map hasher(blake2_128_concat) (u128, u128, String) => bool;
```

Neither its accepts `String`, nor `Vec<u128>`, it says not found in this scope.

Update:
Fixed the Vec part by importing

```
use sp_std::vec::Vec;
```

How can I import string?? Unable to use [str](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v2.0.0/sp_std/str/index.html)?

Will I use `Vec<u8>`? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221904/how-can-i-save-string-value-on-substrate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also import `sp_std::prelude::*` for common stuff, such as `Vec<_>`. For string, as noted in your link, you cannot do it and can use `Vec<u8>` instead.