# Can string be used in substrate?

Tags: substrate

There is sp_std module, https://docs.rs/sp-std/3.0.0/sp_std/fmt/index.html

But using format! or string gives error:

```
 let vote_string = format!("{}-{}", account_string, phrase_string);
```

error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope

```
let phrase_string = String::from_utf8(phrase.clone()).unwrap();
```

^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `String`

Importing
`use sp_std::string::String;`
doesnot work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I save string value on Substrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221904/how-can-i-save-string-value-on-substrate)

Comment: No, its for storing strings as Vec<u8>,  I need string functions like string concatenation, which is not possible using Vec<u8>

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be doing things like string manipulation in your runtime. It usually implies that you are not using your runtime correctly for critical consensus driven logic. However, to concatenate two strings as `Vec<u8>`, you simply extend one vec with the other. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Runtime Building: String not found in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348505/runtime-building-string-not-found-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's answer in the comments above is best:

> In general, you shouldn't be doing things like string manipulation in your runtime. It usually implies that you are not using your runtime correctly for critical consensus driven logic. However, to concatenate two strings as Vec, you simply extend one vec with the other. doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append

For more explanation, see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65348505/runtime-building-string-not-found-in-this-scope)